# Azure backup and autoscaling for EventGrid, Logic app, azure function and Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-autoscaling-block

how to do auto backup and autoscaling for following:
1. API Gateway
2. Event Grid
3. Azure Function
4. Logic App
5. Cosmos DB
6. Web App service?